How to resolve KeyError when chaining llmss
I'm trying to create a process where I can break down a user query into multiple searchable queries using LLMs and then fetch the results online. I've set up two chains for extracting information and searching, but encountered a KeyError: 'analysis' during execution.
Here’s the relevant code snippet::
search_tool = DuckDuckGoSearchRun()

extract_chain = (
    extract_prompt
    | llm
    | StrOutputParser()
)

search_chain = (
    search_prompt
    | llm
    | StrOutputParser()
)

chain = {"analysis" : extract_chain} | {"search_results": lambda x: search_tool.run(x["analysis"])} | search_chain

What could be the cause of this error?

Did you try printing the result of running the search_tool? It looks like the key 'analysis` is absent in its response

If I run connect the outputs directly from one to another it works. So I don't think this is the issue.
